# Prevent query insert spam

Tags: php, mysqli, spam, time-limiting

I got a comment system, where users can post what they think about certain things, however if you press the “Post!” button multiple times, multiple queries are insert into the database and the result is spam.

This is my code:

```
if(!empty($_POST["artcomment"])) {
    $postComment = $DB->real_escape_string($_POST["artcomment"]);
    $poster = $dbuser;
    $postDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    $attachId = $id;

    $prepareComment = $DB->prepare("INSERT INTO article_comments (attach_id, comment, poster, date) VALUES ('".$attachId."', '".$postComment."', '".$poster."', '".$postDate."')");
    $addComment = $prepareComment->execute();
}
```

Now am I wondering if it’s possible to set a time limit of 60 seconds, as if they run the query once (individually!) you have to wait 60 seconds before it can execute the query again. I’ve had a look at `set_time_limit()` but I’m not entirely sure how that works.

Comment: Side note: use [prepared statement and variable binding](http://jp2.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually escaping string and stuffing data into SQL query.

Comment: real_escape_string() and prepare()? There is something fishy about that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store timestamp of last query to session and then compare it when got new request.

```
session_start();
$limit = 60;
$reqEpoch = time();
$ts = (isset($_SESSION['ts'])) ? $_SESSION['ts'] : $reqEpoch;

if ($ts < $reqEpoch - $limit) {
    // run query

    $_SESSION['ts'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Good idea. Will try it out!

Comment: Tried the code you gave me, whenever I try to add a comment it doesn't allow me to add a comment, and I haven't post anything yet. No effect when destroying sessions and re-trying either.

Comment: It stopped working and I have not changed anything. It seem like the if statement fails. Any help?